# Task scheduling with the constraint of pairs of objects being present in a cache

Tags: algorithms, optimization, scheduling

I'm writing some software that involves processing a large collection of images that are arranged spatially. It basically involves loading pairs of images into caches and computing an operation on the pairs. I'm neglecting the cost of computation as it can't be avoided, but loading into the caches from network/disk *does* have a significant avoidable cost. So I'm wondering how I can schedule the loads/evicts from/into the caches to minimize cost.

In case this is unclear, I have formalized the problem below to the best of my ability:

- There are two sets A and B
- There are two "caches" C<sub>A</sub> and C<sub>B</sub> that can contain up to n and m elements of A and B, respectively
- Given a set of pairs (a∈A, b∈B) P, the operation f(a,b) be computed for each pair
- For f(a,b) to be computed, a and b must be loaded into their respective "cache"
- Loading an element into the caches costs L<sub>A</sub> and L<sub>B</sub>, respectively
- Evicting from the caches costs E<sub>A</sub> and E<sub>B</sub>, respectively
- Given those constraints, generate a schedule of Loads and Evictions that minimizes total cost, and guarantees that at some point all (a∈A, b∈B)∈P exists in the cache so the operation f can be computed

So I guess I have two questions regarding this problem:

- Is there any literature that I can read to learn how I might be able to solve it
- Does this problem seem feasible for convex optimization solvers with constraints like Gurobi or Ipopt?